# Web API and Ninject Filter Causing Sequence contains no elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I keep getting this error trying to bind a filter with all actions in an a web api controller.  I am using Ninject 3.0 and ASP.NET MVC 4.

```
<Response>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>Sequence contains no elements</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Ninject.Web.WebApi.FilterBindingSyntax.FilterFilterBindingBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass15`1.<WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute>b__14(IContext ctx, HttpConfiguration controllerContext, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) in d:\Projects\Ninject.Web.WebApi\src\Ninject.Web.WebApi\FilterBindingSyntax\FilterFilterBindingBuilder.cs:line 385 at Ninject.Web.WebApi.FilterBindingSyntax.FilterFilterBindingBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass12.<WithConstructorArgument>b__11(IContext ctx) in d:\Projects\Ninject.Web.WebApi\src\Ninject.Web.WebApi\FilterBindingSyntax\FilterFilterBindingBuilder.cs:line 363 at Ninject.Parameters.Parameter.<>c__DisplayClass6.<.ctor>b__4(IContext ctx, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Parameters\Parameter.cs:line 60 at Ninject.Parameters.Parameter.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Parameters\Parameter.cs:line 89 at
```

**BaseApiController.cs**

```
[ExceptionHandling, ApiValidation, HttpHeader("X-Robots-Tag", "noindex, nofollow")]
    public abstract class BaseApiController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
    {
        protected readonly IApiAuthenticationService ApiAuthenticationService;

        protected BaseApiController(
            IApiAuthenticationService apiAuthenticationService)
        {
            ApiAuthenticationService = apiAuthenticationService;
        }
    }
```

**Global.asax**

```
kernel.BindHttpFilter<HttpHeaderFilter>(System.Web.Http.Filters.FilterScope.Controller)
                       .WhenControllerHas<HttpHeaderAttribute>()
                       .WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute<HttpHeaderAttribute>("name", q => q.Name)
                       .WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute<HttpHeaderAttribute>("value", q => q.Value);
```

**HttpHeaderFilter.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace Tournaments.Models.Mvc.Filters
{
    public class HttpHeaderAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.FilterAttribute 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public HttpHeaderAttribute(string name, string value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    public class HttpHeaderFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly string _name;
        private readonly string _value;

        public HttpHeaderFilter(string name, string value)
        {
            _name = name;
            _value = value;
        }

        public bool AllowMultiple
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
        {
            actionContext.Response.Headers.Add(_name, _value);

            return continuation();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attribute is on the Controller. You must use `WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute` in this case.

Comment: Have you even tried? Even if it doesn't then WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute is the wrong method in your case.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Remo has significant experience with Ninject. Either way, you need to explain yourself better than a muttering such as 'I dont think so'. Comments like that should be flagged (which I havent done yet and Remo is too nice to do)

Comment: @RemoGloor - is there any website/resource that I can read how to add and configure Ninject.Web.WebApi to an existing project? 
Any sample code/project (beside github source code)?